# how to change the data of UItableview?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I have a main menu in my app with 15 item and each item has a sub of 20 items which i also added them as images array (15 image array , some thing like a restaurant menu ) so when ever the user clicks on 1 of the main menu items the app will take him to the sub menu , i have created the main menu table view the issue is with the sub menus do i have to create 15 table view for each sub menu !!??

is there is any way to create 1 table view for the sub menus and change its  data according to user click

note : i don't want to use the sections in my table view

any ideas will be much appreciated

Comment: Think you have two options, 1. Create another view controller for submenu that is very easy like you created the main menu.
2. if you are willing to stick with the same controller and just want to create sub menu then use of expandable section would be the best approach, just do some research on accordion view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Need two viewControllers and a navigationController. One for main menu and other for sub menu. Let them be mainMenuViewController and subMenuViewController. Each controllers contains a tableView.
2. Create an menuArray containing 15 submenu data.Each submenu is an array.
3. In didSelectRowAtIndexPath of mainMenuViewController, if user selects a row in the tableView, then pass that data in the menuArray corresponding to the selected row.

For example, if user selects third row,
then  pass menuArray[3] to subMenuViewController. Here indexPath.row = 3.

### Sample Project Code:

### MenuViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class MenuViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var menuTableView: UITableView!
    var  imagesArray: NSArray = []
    var  menuArray: NSArray = []
    var  subMenuDataArray: NSArray = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        menuTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        imagesArray = ["soups.jpg","salads.jpg","starters.jpg","pizzas.jpg","burgers.jpeg"]

        menuArray = ["Soups","Salads","Starters","Pizzas","Burgers"]

        subMenuDataArray = [["Cream of broccoli","Cream of celery","Cream of tomato","Etrog","Gazpacho"],
                            ["Tuna salad","Urnebes","Waldorf salad"],
                            ["Kakori Kebabs","Stir Fried Chilli Chicken"," Microwave Paneer Tikkas","Aloo and Dal ki Tikki","Cheese Balls","Bhuna Masala Chicken Wings"],
                            ["Cheese Pizzas","Chicken Pizzas","Masala Pizzas","Double Cheese Pizzas","Herbal Pizzas"],
                            ["Luger Burger","Le Pigeon Burger","The Company Burger","Dyer’s Deep-Fried Burger","The Lola Burger","Cheeseburger","Raw Steak Tartare Burger","Buckhorn Burger"]]

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

        return imagesArray.count

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat{
        return 70

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

        let  menuTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let cellImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView.init()
        cellImageView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50)
        cellImageView.image =  UIImage(named: imagesArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! String)
        menuTableViewCell.contentView.addSubview(cellImageView)

        let  menuLabel: UILabel = UILabel.init(frame: CGRectMake(70, 10, 200, 25))
        menuLabel.text = menuArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? String
        menuTableViewCell.contentView.addSubview(menuLabel)


        return menuTableViewCell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

        let subMenuViewController: SubMenuViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SubMenuViewControllerID") as! SubMenuViewController
        subMenuViewController.currentSubMenuArray = subMenuDataArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSArray
        navigationController?.pushViewController(subMenuViewController, animated: true)


    }


}
```

### SubMenuViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class SubMenuViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var subMenuTableView: UITableView!
    var  currentSubMenuArray: NSArray = []


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

         subMenuTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "subCell")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return currentSubMenuArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let  subMenuTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("subCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let  subMenuLabel: UILabel = UILabel.init(frame: CGRectMake(10, 10, 250, 25))
        subMenuLabel.text = currentSubMenuArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? String
        subMenuTableViewCell.contentView.addSubview(subMenuLabel)
        return subMenuTableViewCell
    }


}
```

### Storyboard:

[image]

### Output:

[image]

To test the sample project, use the following link of my GitHub account:

https://github.com/k-sathireddy/MenuTableViewSample

Comment: ok man , plz could u show me where to define and how to pass the chosen array to the subMenuViewController

Answer (score 1):

Declare one array for displaying and change the content of the array according to the selection and screen state like for menu, submenu etc. and reload the table to display the data in the main array. And if you want to display different kind of cell for different selection you can achieve it by taking an enum for whats the current screen state like i said and return required cell initialized in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Its all about how much you can think and implement the logic. Comment below if you need real technical solution with codes you already have used.